# Store and get values from Perl hash tables

Tags: perl

I want to store names in hash or array, which are in format

```
(e.g apple<->banana , orange<->papaya).
```

And now I have half information like `apple or papaya` which I need to look in that hash table and get the full combination `apple<->banana` and store it in a variable... :)

Hope my question is clear actually i read few hash documents and every where it's mentioned to search with full name ... so I need to search with half name or 1st word.

Comment: Please, clarify what the input is and what is the expected output. You description is unfortunately unclear.

Comment: [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Comment: input values apple   and expected value apple<->banana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input file is like:

```
apple<->banana
orange<->papaya
```

Here is a way to do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %corresp;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($k, $v) = split/<->/,$_;
    $corresp{$k} = $v;
}
my %reverse = reverse %corresp;

my $search = 'apple';
if (exists$corresp{$search}) {
    say "$search = $corresp{$search}";
} elsif(exists$reverse{$search}) {
    say "$search = $reverse{$search}";
} else {
    say 'No match!';
}

__DATA__
apple<->banana
orange<->papaya
```

Comment: Thanks M42 !!! Is your script is looking reverse also ? I mean I have input file apple<->banana , orange<->papaya ,kilo<->lima.... if any of the value macthes I need there full connection. either way ? we we grep for banana or apple full link should come apple<->banana..

Comment: @user3457622: Yes, it works forr both direct and reverse search.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
my %hash = (
    'apple' => 'banana',
    'orange' => 'papaya'
);

## the word is looking for
my $word = 'orange';

## checking using Key
if(defined($hash{$word})){
    print "$word <=> $hash{$word}";
}

## checking using value
else{
    ## handling only one value, not all
    my ($key) = grep { $hash{$_} eq $word } keys %hash;
    print "$key <=> $hash{$key}" if $key;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sabuj, How the word look for ## the word is looking for
my $word = 'orange'; incase if it papaya will i get connection option ..connectin means orange<->papaya ... can i use simly grep like in linux ..if we grep we get full information... ?

Comment: If you use `papaya`, it will check for every `values` in hash and look for the word `papaya`. grep is doing that here, and returning the `$key=orange`